# Docker build complains it can't find nuget fallback package folder

Tags: docker, .net-core, nuget

I'm following the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/docker-basics-dotnet-core#dockerize-the-net-core-application in learning to containerise .net core applications into Docker.

Other than changing the `Dockerfile` to point at `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk` as a base image, and adding a `RUN dotnet --info` line to get version/environment information, everything else is the same. However, I'm getting an error on the `dotnet publish` step:

```
Step 7/8 : RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
 ---> Running in 6739267c7581
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.166+gd4e8d81a88 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 34.46 ms for /app/Hello.csproj.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error MSB4018: The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly. [/app/Hello.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error MSB4018: NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'. [/app/Hello.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error MSB4018:    at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders) [/app/Hello.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(LockFile lockFile, String projectPath) [/app/Hello.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task, Stream stream) [/app/Hello.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash) [/app/Hello.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task) [/app/Hello.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups() [/app/Hello.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore() [/app/Hello.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [/app/Hello.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/app/Hello.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/app/Hello.csproj]
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o out' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

So far the only thing I can find on the subject is some github issues requesting that the fallback folder is ditched in Docker as it bloats the container. At this stage I'm not concerned too much about bloat, I just want it to build a hello world application.

---

In case it is helpful the `dotnet --info` command returned the following:

```
Step 3/8 : RUN dotnet --info
 ---> Running in 17dad2f04a7e
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.401
 Commit:    91b1c13032

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  9
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         debian.9-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.3
  Commit:  124038c13e

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.401 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of `/app/Hello.csproj`? Your docker container is running Debian, where a path like `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder` can not possibly exist. Is this path hardcoded in your project somewhere?

Answer (score 48):

The problem is some lingering files in your bin and obj directories, which you don't need to build your app from source. Therefore I think the best solution is to add the bin and obj directories into a .dockerignore file, which will exclude those folders from copying into your Docker context, resulting in a small performance boost. Here's what my .dockerignore file looks like for dotnet apps:

```
.dockerignore
.env
.git
.gitignore
.vs
.vscode
docker-compose.yml
docker-compose.*.yml
**/bin
**/obj
bin/
obj/
```

Answer (score 45):

This is likely due to the `obj\project.assests.json` file that is generated by Visual Studio when you open the project. If you look in there, you'll find reference to your NuGet package folders in your Windows system.

e.g.

```
"packageFolders": {
  "C:\\Users\\<UserName>\\.nuget\\packages\\": {},
  "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder": {}
},
```

A simple workaround is to add a step in your Dockerfile to delete the `bin` and `obj` files before it runs any restore, build or test step. One way to do that is to make use of the `find` program:

```
find -type d -name bin -prune -exec rm -rf {} \; && find -type d -name obj -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Using the Dockerfile from the tutorial you linked to as an example, that would look something like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . ./
RUN find -type d -name bin -prune -exec rm -rf {} \; && find -type d -name obj -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/Hello.dll"]
```

Comment: In my situation deletion of obj and bin folders before run `docker build .` resolved the casue.

Comment: This was actually it. I have my CI build my Dockerfiles (and so `obj` and `bin` is excluded from git), but I made some changes to the Dockerfile and wanted to try them out locally.. Thanks! :-)

Comment: I had this start happening today on a .net core 3.1 build on Azure DevOps. It's not looking for a Windows reference for the fallback folder (`Unable to find fallback package folder '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder'`), but it's definitely not looking in the right place. Adding the `find` command just before the `Run dotnet build` line in my dockerfile has solved the problem, but I wish I knew why. Both `bin` and `obj` are excluded in the `.gitignore` and the `.dockerignore`

Comment: I'm having the same issue and both this answer and the .dockerignore resolution are not working for me. Also restarted docker with no luck. When I run the find command error NETSDK1004: Assets file '/src/src/Sherlock.WorkerService/obj/project.assets.json' not found

Answer (score 4):

if your docker container is of the linux family, add this flag `-r linux-x64` to the publish command, this flag should cover building for "(Most desktop distributions like CentOS, Debian, Fedora, Ubuntu, and derivatives)"; so the publish command should look like this `RUN dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c Release -o out`
for other RIDs refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

Answer (score 4):

You could add a `.dockerignore` file so that it ignores any `obj` directories created locally when building the image with docker, e.g. put this in `.dockerignore`. This works for me.

```
*/obj/*
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after checking that with all of these responses the problem persisted, the only solution was to restart docker desktop.